# Can''t insert into table

Tags: php, mysql

The intended purpose of this script is to add an item to something that resembles a shopping cart. when the user clicks a button the script below should load.

the script starts by getting the product id for the product name that has been entered in a form.

this is then put into a variable.

The INSERT query is then performed, using the LAST_INSERT_ID() method to the ID of the last order that was added

```
if(isset($_GET['submit1']))
{
$db_product_name = $_GET['product_name'];

$query  = "SELECT ProductID FROM product WHERE Product_Name = '$db_product_name'";
$result = mysql_query($query)
or die(mysql_error());
$fetch = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$db_productid = $fetch['ProductID'];

$query = "INSERT INTO `the_shop`.order_line_item(
`OrderID`
`ProductID`
)
VALUES (
`LAST_INSERT_ID()`, `$db_productid`)";
$result = mysql_query($query)
or die(mysql_error());
}
```

However I get the following error:

> You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
>   for the right syntax to use near '`ProductID` ) VALUES (
>   `LAST_INSERT_ID()`, `..`)' at line 3

Comment: You forgot the comma in  (OrderID `,` ProductID)

Comment: No offence intended but if you're having trouble debugging things like this, you _should not_ be writing a sales system yet. That's not intended as an insult, we've all been where you are, but making a mistake while handling money can have expensive consequences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have missed comma after `OrderID`

```
INSERT INTO `the_shop`.order_line_item(
    `OrderID`, -- <---- here is a missed comma
    `ProductID`
)
```

Mysql always points to a part of the query it cannot parse. It means that syntactic error occurred right **before** the cited part

Comment: In connection with the missed comma, the values also were wrapped with backticks when it should be a single quote `:)`

Comment: @JW 웃: it's a homework :-) Now OP (I hope) knows how to interpret error messages

Comment: just changed the backticks to single quotes but it stopped working again.

nope not homework.

This is part of a sales order processing system

Comment: @Chris Bennett: "homework" in this case means - now you have sufficient knowledge to solve further issues without our help. "This is part of a sales order processing system" --- the better it would be to be a part of a real home work )))

Comment: oh indeed :)

I got to try and get this LAST_INSERT_ID working